# Could not load file or assembly 'Skybound.Gecko' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format

Tags: c#

IN VS 2010 works fine but in IIS 7 i get this error. Windows is x64 and it looks like to me that gecko is x86 compiled. But why works at VS 2010 then?

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Could not load file or assembly 'Skybound.Gecko' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Skybound.Gecko' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Skybound.Gecko' could not be loaded.

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].


Stack Trace:

[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Skybound.Gecko' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +567
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +192
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +35
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +118

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'Skybound.Gecko' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +11392147
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +484
   System.Web.Configuration.AssemblyInfo.get_AssemblyInternal() +127
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +334
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods() +280
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +1087

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'Skybound.Gecko' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +11524352
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +141
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +11356670


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Edit your application pool advanced proeprties, you should find an `Enable 32-Bit Applications` flag and set it to true. Ensure you compile in visual studio with a platform target x86.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

if it works on vs2010 it should work in iis7.

1. skyboud.gecko has some dependencies that cannot be found . the best way to know the dependencies is to use redgate reflector.
   also set the following key to HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1 
   on the server. (P.S dont know if that is possible in your env.)
   The log generally explains which assembly could not be loaded.

You can then T.S the issue further.

Comment: *An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format* typically means x86 vs. x64, typically an Any CPU compiled program loading a 32-bit assembly, but running on a 64-bit OS.